# Unable to decrypt file that was PGP encrypted on server

Tags: encryption, pgp, openpgp

I created a PGP public/private key using the following command from my local machine

```
gpg --full-generate-key --openpgp
```

I encrypt a file using Golang code(https://github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp), and the BouncyCastle Java library decrypts the file(on a different server). Encryption and decryption work when I encrypt the file from my local machine. Decryption fails when I run the same code on my server to encrypt the file. I also noticed that the encrypted file packets differ when I encrypt on my local machine vs. the server. I am using the following command to list packets.

```
gpg --list-packets ~/encrypted_file_name.pgp
```

Is it possible to use the public key on the server-generated on my local machine? How to do PGP encryption on a server?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not at all clear what code is running where and what code isn't working. You mention apparently 3 distinct pieces of software, the gpg command line, a Go program, and a Java program, and 3 different execution environments your "local" machine, some "other server" somewhere, and "your server" somewhere. Please clarify what's happening, provide a [mre] for the failing code, and include complete error information, not just "decryption fails".

Answer (score 0):

It is probably worth double checking everything outside your code using the gpg cli to rule out weirder issues.

On the encrypting side run:

```
# list the keys and grab the key id you expect, it should be 40 characters uppercase+numbers
gpg --list-keys
# encrypt a message for that ID
echo 'test' | gpg -ear <KEY_ID>
```

Copy the output of the above to your clipboard, then on the decrypting server run the following:

```
# list the secret keys available, there must be one in this list with the exact same KEY_ID from above
gpg --list-secret-keys
# make sure you can use that key by decrypting the message from the first step
cat <<EOF | gpg -d
<paste the message>
EOF
```

If this works then we'll probably need you to put together code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Only the one who encoded it into or onto a program, etc is able to decode or decrypt it via the certificate as required along with a passphase that would be applied no one can access unless digital signature matches, certificate and passphase.

Comment: Since op is the one who encrypted the file, I think it's safe to assume that they have the certificate and the passphrase.